# LM3900: different input impedances in symmetric pins?

Tags: amplifier, schematics, differential-amplifier, input-impedance, current-mirror

Referring to the LM3900 "Quadruple Norton Operational Amplifiers" [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3900.pdf), consider the schematic of each single amplifier at page 1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkYkX9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In its first stage, the device performs the difference between the currents \$ I_{\mathrm{in}}^-\ - I_{\mathrm{in}}^+\$ at its input pins, respectively the currents entering the `IN-` and the `IN+` pins.

The `IN+` is the collector of the input (reference current) branch of a [current mirror](https://hardwarebee.com/current-mirror/), so it is actually a collector short-circuited to the base, in the diode-connected transistor Q1. The input impedance seen from the `IN+` pin is therefore very low, ideally zero, as it is for the input of a current mirror.

The situation looking into the `IN-` pin looks very different: it is the collector of Q2, not diode-connected, so it is a high impedance, and however *higher* than the `IN+` (other than the base of Q2, which still probably absorbs a negligible current).

How is it possible that such pins do not have a perfectly symmetrical condition? How can the difference \$ I_{\mathrm{in}}^-\ - I_{\mathrm{in}}^+\$ be correctly realized, with such an unbalanced situation?

---

The bases of Q1 and Q2 share the same current: it is a (probably small) portion of the current coming from `IN+`. Regardless of this, it seems to me that the impedance seen from `IN+` is very low (input of a current mirror), while the impedance seen from `IN-` is very high (output of a current mirror). If this is correct, why does this circuit work properly anyway?

Answer (score 1):

> *The base of Q2 (the other branch of the current mirror) is also
> connected to the same node, but with a higher impedance and probably
> absorbing a negligible current.*

No, that's not how a current mirror works. Within the bounds of reason, the same current flowing into Q1's base will flow into Q2's base. Hence Q2's collector subtracts \$I_{IN}^+\$ from \$I_{IN}^-\$ on the \$IN-\$ node: -

[image]

Comment: Yes, probably I didn't phrase it precisely, but I agree as regards the currents \$ I_x \$. My doubt is about the input impedances instead: isn't the input impedance seen from `IN+` much lower than the input impedance seen from `IN-`? Why?

Comment: @BowPark consider the case of \$I_X\$ flowing into both input pins. There will be zero current into Q3's base. Remember also that the transistor picture is not reality; it's just representative.

Comment: If \$ I_x = I_{\mathrm{in}}^+ = I_{\mathrm{in}}^- \$ yes, Q3 will have no input. But how is this related to the individual input impedances seen from the `IN+` and `IN-` pins?

Comment: @BowPark the input impedances will be the same; IN+ sees effectively a base emitter diode and the main current into the collector of Q1 and so does IN- (because it sees a current equal to Ix and a base emitter diode of Q3.

Comment: @BowPark remember also that the base currents into Q1 and Q2 are a tiny fraction of current Ix (the mirrored current. This will nominally produce about a 1% difference in input impedance due to IN+ connecting to two base-emitter junctions (rather than just one for IN-). The 1% figure is based on a BJT beta of 100. More modern transistors will be 200+ in beta value.

Comment: @BowPark If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: Maybe the effect of the Q1 and Q2 base currents on the input impedances can be neglected. I still have confusion: the impedance seen from `IN+` is the input of a current mirror and it is low, while the impedance seen from `IN-` is very high, because it is the output of a current mirror. I can not see the equivalence between them, and I can not see the role of Ix, which may also be absent, if `IN+` is 0. By Ix I am meaning a small signal overlapped to a bias or a DC signal, so all the transistors are always on and biased.

Comment: I think the confusion arises over what you mean by impedance, I'm taking it to mean the impedance of IN+ and IN- when both are identical voltages. If we talk about the impedance of one on its own, that impedance will vary as the source voltage rises i.e. below around 0.4 volts there is barely any current flowing into IN+. That has to be a high impedance but, if that voltage rose by 100 mV then, the current  would increase tenfold due to the diode non-linearity of Q1. So we have to regard both inputs fed an identical voltage. Now can you see why their impedances are very nearly identical.

Answer (score 1):

I've taken the liberty of copying and annotating the actual schematic from the datasheet.

[image]

Both inputs have no more voltage drop than a diode junction. The inverting input may have a lower voltage if the non-inverting input current is large (in the extreme Q1 saturates and the non-inverting input has a voltage drop of tens of mV at low input currents.

When the amplifier is active (not railed) at the output, the input currents are approximately balanced, but some small current flows into Q2 (otherwise the output would be railed high due to the 200uA current source).

Q1 and the diode (likely a diode-connected transistor as you have shown) form a current mirror so that Q1 collector sinks approximately as much current as flows into the non-inverting input from the inverting input. So Q2 base sees the difference between the two currents.

In many cases we don't really have constant current sources for the inputs (and the gain is not that high in any case) so these Norton amplifiers are not really precision devices, but good enough for some applications.

Comment: This is a useful overview of the whole circuit. But I still can't get, from your observations, how the pins `IN+` and `IN-` offer the same input impedance to a signal. They look different: `IN+` is looking into Q1 base and into a low-impedance current mirror input. `IN-` has not the same "favourable" condition: it is also looking into a base (the base of Q2), but also into the collector of Q1, which is not diode-connected (so which offers a different impedance with respect to `IN+`).

Comment: They don't offer the exact same impedance, especially for relatively low voltages applied.

Comment: Ok, this is helping. My doubt was: what are the (qualitative, not numerical) differences between the two input impedances and why this is not a problem for the circuit? I can not understand it from your answer. If you can, if you want, you can expand it.

Comment: I guess part of the problem is that “impedance” is a function of input current (maybe both input currents). If you have a current source attached to the inputs the “impedance” does not matter because it is in series with a much higher impedance (of the source). To the extent it is not a perfect current source there will be an error term.